# Linear transformations of fields

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory

Let $K$ be field. Show if $f: K \to K$ is linear transformation, then there exists $a \in K$ such that for every $x \in K$, $f(x) = ax$

I don't know how to prove it but for instance $a = 1$ satisfy the conditions (I think so, not sure)

Answer (score 1):

Hints: it must be that

$$\;\forall\,x\in K\;,\;\;f(x)=f(x\cdot1)=xf(1)$$

So what do you think $\;a\;$ **would (must)** be?

Comment: so a must be 1 , thanks

Comment: @jonathan Not at all. Think it a little longer.

Comment: ok so taking $a=f(1)$ we have such $a$ that conditions are satisfied ?

Comment: That's correct, @jonathan